# Automated decomposition of a large symbolic matrix for faster determinant calculation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, simplifying-expressions

I have this $44$ dimensional parametric matrix ($\{x,d,b,t\}\in\mathbb{R}$) and I want to compute its determinant.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to predict how much time it will take to give a result by `Det[M]`?
2. Is it possible to decompose the matrix (as a multiplication of simpler matrices) so that computing its determinant is faster? Can this be done using automated functionality provided by Mathematica?

```
M:={{-E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 0, 
  0, -E^(I b - (2 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (-1 + x), 
  E^(-(2/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1 + x, 
  1 - x, -E^(I b - (2 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (1 + x), 
  E^(-(2/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1 + x, -1 - x, 1 + x, 1 - x, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), 0, 0, -1 + x, -1 - x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (1 + x), 
  E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (1 - x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((4 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (-1 - x), 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 - x, 1 + x, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0}, {E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 - x, -1 + x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 0, 
  0, -E^(I b - (6 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (-1 + x), 
  E^(-(6/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), -E^(
    I b - (6 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (1 + x), 
  E^(-(6/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 1 + x, 1 - x, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), 0, 0, -1 + x, -1 - x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (1 + x), 
  E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (1 - x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((8 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (-1 - x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 1 - x, 1 + x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 - x, -1 + x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(I b - (10 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (-1 + x), 
  E^(-(10/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x),
   E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 0, 
  0, -E^(I b - (10 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (1 + x), 
  E^(-(10/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 1 + x, 1 - x, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 + x, -1 - x, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 
  E^((12 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (1 + x), 
  E^((12 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (1 - x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((12 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((12 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (-1 - x), 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 - x, 1 + x, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), -1 - x, -1 + x, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 0, 
  0, -E^(I b - (14 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (-1 + x), 
  E^(-(14/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), -E^(
    I b - (14 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (1 + x), 
  E^(-(14/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 1 + x, 1 - x, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), 0, 0, -1 + x, -1 - x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -E^(I b - (18 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (-1 + x), 
  E^(-(18/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x),
   E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 0, 
  0, -E^(I b - (18 I d \[Pi])/11 - I x) (1 + x), 
  E^(-(18/11) I d \[Pi] + I (b + x)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 1 + x, 1 - x, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1 + x, -1 - x, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -E^(I (t - x)) (1 + x), 
  E^(I (t + x)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, E^(I (b - x)) (1 - x), E^(I (b + x)) (1 + x)}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 0, 
  0, -E^(I (b - x)) (1 + x), E^(I (b + x)) (-1 + x)}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 1 + x, 
  1 - x}, {0, 0, E^(I (t - x)) (1 - x), E^(I (t + x)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 + x, -1 - x}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((16 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (1 + x), 
  E^((16 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (1 - x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), E^((16 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((16 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (-1 - x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 1 - x, 1 + x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, -1 - x, -1 + x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 0, 0, 
  E^((20 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (1 + x), 
  E^((20 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (1 - x), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), E^((20 I d \[Pi])/11 + I (-b + x)) (-1 + x), 
  E^((20 I d \[Pi])/11 - I (b + x)) (-1 - x), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -E^(-((I x)/2)) (1 + x), 
  E^((I x)/2) (-1 + x), 1 - x, 1 + x, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E^((I x)/2) (1 + x), -E^(-((I x)/2)) (-1 + x), 0, 
  0, -1 - x, -1 + x, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: **how much time it will take to give a result by Det[M]** I think the best known algorithm is $O(n^{2.372...})$ where $n$ is the size of the matrix.

Comment: **Is it possible to decompose the matrix (as a multiplication of simpler matrices) so that computing its determinant is faster?** I think this is now a math question so might be better ask at the math forum.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your comments; as for your first comment then what is $\mathcal{O}(44^{2.372})$? As for the second comment, I thought maybe there is a Mathematica command for the decomposition of matrices.

Comment: I am not sure it will make it faster if you change your one matrix, with multiplication of number of $m$ matrices instead and then find determinant of each of these and multiply the determinants.  Since time to find the determinant is function of size of the matrix, and each one of the $m$ matrices has to be $n$ also, then this might actually be slower to do.  But may be someone at math group knows more about this. As for the order, this is big O, it just says this is how you would expect the time to increase as a function of changing $n$. It does not give an actual time or anything like that.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: Define the two permutations `p1={33,36,34,35,42,43,41,44,29,32,30,31,38,39,37,40,25,28,26,27,22,23,21,24,17,20,18,19,14,15,13,16,9,12,10,11,6,7,5,8,1,4,2,3}` and `p2={3,4,43,44,39,40,41,42,37,38,35,36,31,32,33,34,25,26,29,30,27,28,23,24,21,22,19,20,15,16,17,18,9,10,13,14,11,12,7,8,1,2,5,6}`. Define `X=M[[p1,p2]]`. If you display `X`, you will see that it has a simpler structure than `M` (also try `ListPlot[Map[First,ArrayRules[X]]]`). Note that `X` and `M` have the same determinant, because `p1` and `p2` are even permutations. I do not know how to calculate the determinant of `X` however.

Comment: @user293787 Thanks. It does not look simpler; it is again  $44$ dimensional matrix with four nonzero entries on each row.

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer but an elaboration on my comment above.*

One can use

```
MatrixPlot[M]
```

to see the sparse structure of `M`:

[image]

Define the even permutations

```
p1={33,36,34,35,42,43,41,44,29,32,30,31,38,39,37,40,25,28,26,27,22,23,21,24,17,20,18,19,14,15,13,16,9,12,10,11,6,7,5,8,1,4,2,3};
p2={3,4,43,44,39,40,41,42,37,38,35,36,31,32,33,34,25,26,29,30,27,28,23,24,21,22,19,20,15,16,17,18,9,10,13,14,11,12,7,8,1,2,5,6};
```

and set `X=M[[p1,p2]]`. Note that $\det M = \det X$, hence our goal is to compute $\det X$.

Using

```
MatrixPlot[X]
```

we get

[image]

In fact, the matrix $X$ has the following structure:
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & B_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & A_2 & B_2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & A_3 & \cdots & 0 & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & A_{n-1} & B_{n-1} \\
B_n & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & A_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where each $A_i$ and each $B_i$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, and where $n = 22$.

The determinant of such a matrix has the following formula, if the $A_i$ are invertible:
$$
\det X = \det(A_1) \det(A_2) \cdots \det(A_n) \det\Big(
1 - (-1)^n A_1^{-1} B_1 A_2^{-1} B_2 \cdots A_n^{-1} B_n
\Big)
$$
This can be obtained by applying the [block matrix determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant) repeatedly. Alternatively, to convince oneself that this formula is correct, one can use the Mathematica code given below. It is easy to calculate the $\det(A_i)$, but the difficult part is
$$
\det\Big(
1 - (-1)^n A_1^{-1} B_1 A_2^{-1} B_2 \cdots A_n^{-1} B_n
\Big)
$$
This is the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix, easy in principle, but in OPs case where the entries are symbolic, it is not so easy.

**Code to check the formula for $\det X$.**

```
n=22;
Clear[A,B];
A[i_]:=A[i]=RandomInteger[{-10,10},{2,2}];
B[i_]:=B[i]=RandomInteger[{-10,10},{2,2}];
Det[ArrayFlatten[Table[Switch[Mod[i-j,n],0,A[i],n-1,B[i],_,0],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}]]]===Product[Det[A[i]],{i,1,n}]*Det[IdentityMatrix[2]-(-1)^n*Dot@@Table[Inverse[A[i]].B[i],{i,1,n}]]
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you obtain $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: I first looked at `ListPlot[Most[Map[First,ArrayRules[M]]]]`. I then used the code `G=Most[Map[First,ArrayRules[M]]];
next1[{x1_,x2_,y1_,y2_}]:=With[{X=Cases[G,{x1|x2,Except[y1|y2]}]},
Join[DeleteDuplicates[X[[;;,1]]],DeleteDuplicates[X[[;;,2]]]]];
next2[{x1_,x2_,y1_,y2_}]:=With[{X=Cases[G,{Except[x1|x2],y1|y2}]},
Join[DeleteDuplicates[X[[;;,1]]],DeleteDuplicates[X[[;;,2]]]]];
next[{x1_,x2_,y1_,y2_}]:=next2[next1[{x1,x2,y1,y2}]];
GX=NestList[next,{33,36,3,4},21];
{Flatten[GX[[;;,{1,2}]]],Flatten[GX[[;;,{3,4}]]]}`. I am not going to explain how it works.